# How to add the $i from the for loop to the end of a url?

Tags: php

I am using a for loop to get the contects of a url that has paging in the form of `pg=1`

However I tried this without luck

```
$html= file_get_contents("http://www.........&pg='.$i.'");
```

Comment: Well, you make the url `&pg='.1.'`, not `&pg=1`. Either concatination (`'string'.$var.'somethingelse`), or variable substitution (`"string$var"`), but don't use both at the same time like this. For future reference, it's always useful to check what a string / variable / function argument contains if something doesn't work.

Comment: please add your complete code here, and i think you should try curl http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `.` characters from around the integer you're appending to the string.  According to the PHP manual:

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it
>   (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php, section "Variable Parsing")

See http://ideone.com/AtcoYi for an example.

---

**EDIT:**

It's unclear to me whether the OP wants the string wrapped in single quotes in the output. If so, leave them in:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.........&pg='$i'");
```

If not, take them out:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.........&pg=$i");
```

Comment: and the single quotes?

Comment: Are treated just like any other character in the string :)

Comment: Ah.  It's unclear to me whether the OP wants the string wrapped in single quotes in the output.  If so, leave them in.  If not, take them out.

Comment: very unlikely he wants `&pg='1'` don't you think he wants `&pg=1`

Answer (score 0):

watch the quote marks

```
$html= file_get_contents("http://www.........&pg=".$i);
```

Comment: i needed to watch them too :)